# Online UDP speed test

Tags: networking, openvpn, udp

I am looking for an online UDP port speed tester. I want to use OpenVpn on UDP, but my ISP is limiting UDP port speed. Is there any tool to batch test UDP port speeds? I want to test multiple ports, maybe not all UDP port is limited.

TCP is working fine, but it's much slower (ping, speed).

Comment: Sorry, voted to close because you are asking for a product recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to an external server where you can install software, [iPerf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iperf) is a commonly used tool for bandwidth testing. By default, the program uses TCP, but you can test UDP, instead, by using the `-u` option to the [iperf command](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/unix/linux/centos/7/man/iperf.php) on the client end. You start one system as the iPerf server with `iperf -s`. On the client side, you could then use `iperf -c example.com -u` where example.com is the [fully qualified domain name (FQDN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) or IP address of the server on which you are running iPerf in server mode. By default the latest version of iPerf, version 3, uses port 5201, but you can set the port using the `-p n` or `--port n` where `n` is the port number you want to use. You would need to specify the port on both client and server, if you aren't using the default port and you will need to set up any needed firewall rules on the server end ([instructions for configuring OS X firewall for iPerf](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/os-x/iperf/)) and, possibly, the client side, if there is a firewall on that side restricting outgoing traffic (for home connections that usually isn't applicable).

Alternatively, there are [public iPerf servers](https://iperf.fr/iperf-servers.php) in various parts of the world that you can use for testing, so that you would only need to install the software on the client side to do some testing. But you will only be able to test with those systems using the default port, port 5201.

Iperf is available for a variety of operating systems, including Linux and OS X. If you are using [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) Linux, you can [install the iperf package on CentOS](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/unix/linux/centos/iperf-install.php) with the [yum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yum_(.rpm)) package manager, if you install support for the EPEL [repository](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_repository). You can also [use iPerf on Microsoft Windows systems](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/software/network/performance/iperf/).

Answer (score 1):

Run: `iperf3 -c iperf.he.net -u -b 0 -k 2k`

Obtain file from: https://iperf.fr/iperf-download.php

Alternatively, instead of iperf.he.net, use any other public server at:
https://iperf.fr/iperf-servers.php

Alternatively, run your own server by running:
`iperf3 -s -V`

To choose your own port number, specify `-p 5201` (5201 seems to be the default for iperf3)